# Spotfire calculate number of days since 'criteria in another column'

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a `[Date]` column and a `[STATUS]` column. `[Status]` can be either "Up" or "Down". I want to count the number of days `[STATUS]="Down"`

```
date          status     new_calculated_column
1/1/2001      up         0
1/2/2001      down       1
1/3/2001      up         0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This will work using `SUM` or `COUNT`

```
SUM(IF([STATUS] = "Down",1,0))
```

or....

```
COUNT(IF([STATUS] = "Down",1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't think I was specific enough in my question. I'm trying to obtain the count for the current period where it is "Down". So, if it is "Up" today, then "Down" tomorrow the count begins with tomorrow and continues to count until the status is "Up" again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries @Chris   Can you post a better data sample and expected output and I'll set you up

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will tomorrow when I get to my computer again. In short, I'm trying to count the number of days it's been since the status column changed (think of it as a manufacturing plant's status runtime).

Comment: I don't think this is possible via custom expression with your limited number of columns. There just isn't any way to group it with an over statement. It can be done in Oracle or SQL Server, or with an R script or iron python.